# Accessing images from network drive

Tags: web-applications

is it possible to access image from network drive and show it in a html page.I'm not sure if its possible to go beyond the web application directory in which the html page resides

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend on the web server and the OS.
For Apache on Linux, you might be able to create a symlink to the network share.
For Windows and IIS, you'll probably have to set up the network share as a web site.

Either way, I don't think it's a good idea.  You have to consider fault tolerance; what if the network share is unavailable?